# Get the training history of Bayesian optimized keras model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tf.keras, bayesian-deep-learning

I used BayesianOptimization to optimize hyper-parameters of a Keras model. I got best_model as a result. Is it possible to get the training history of best_model (training loss and validation loss during epochs)?
I tried to get best_model.history but the result is empty. Thank you for your help

````
tuner_bo = BayesianOptimization(
            hypermodel,
            objective='mse',
            max_trials=10,
            seed=42,
            executions_per_trial=2,
            overwrite=True
        )
tuner_bo.search(x_train_scaled, y_train, epochs=nb_epochs, validation_split=0.2, verbose=0)
best_model = tuner_bo.get_best_models(num_models=1)[0]
pred = best_model.predict(x_test_scaled, batch_size = 32)```
````